# where to find AppCompat.getReferrer() in android support libraries

Tags: android, android-support-library

Where can I find the android support library with [`ActivityCompat.getReferrer()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html) this function ?

I thought it would be in 
my `build.gradle` looks like this: compile **'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.1**'  but its not working.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //Google
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:10.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.1' 

    compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.0.0'
}
```

I am trying to access `ActivityCompat.getReferrer()` from a activity that extends `AppCompatActivity` in android.support.v7.app package but I can't find this method

Comment: Do you mean `ActivityCompat.getReferrer(Activity)`

Comment: yes even that is fine. as long as i can find the referring activity. what dependency should i add. ?

Comment: https://github.com/googlecodelabs/deeplink-referrer/issues/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'` is enough for that method as it is a method of [`ActivityCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#getReferrer(android.app.Activity)). Please use same versions' of libraries from support library.

Java code sanple

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        Uri uri = ActivityCompat.getReferrer(SplashActivity.this);
        if (uri != null)
            Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this,uri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks great. this thing got updated now. i think you need an instance to make the call now. so in your Actvitity class you can just call this.getReferrer(). That was actually my issue. they changed it from a static call to a instance call in another version.